# HTML section identified by URL segment not found within webpage

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

How can I notify the user when the section identified by the url fragment is not found on a webpage?

*Example*:

website1 contains:

```
<a href="/website2#foo"> bring me to the foo section of website2 </a>
```

and website 2 contains:

```
<div id="foo"> I'm the foo section </div>
```

So if I click the link and the identifier of the div is not "foo" but "bar" the webpage displays an alert like "foo section not found".

Context: I'm exposing on an html page a JSON response for an API and I want the attributes of the JSON to link to a documentation page. If the section describing that attribute is not found an alert should suggest to update the documentation.

UPDATE: without using javascript frameworks if possible

Thanks

Comment: But vanilla javascript is ok?

Comment: I think the right approach could be onLoad of website2 check
if(window.location.hash) window.location.hash.substring(1) and then look for that Id using getElementById ..

Comment: @GaSacchi That's exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

On "onLoad" of website2 I check if the url contains a segment and then look for that Id in the document using getElementById(segment) ..

```
<html>
    <body onload="myFunction()">

        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {

            var segment;

            if(window.location.hash){

               segment = window.location.hash.substring(1);

               if( document.getElementById(segment) == null ){

                   alert("html element with id "+segment+" not found");
               }
            }
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2nd `if` can be moved into the first to save a check when there's no hash. Also, do you want the alert to appear when there's a `#` but nothing after it? (i.e. `segment` is empty)

Comment: In my case yes because those Ids will be auto-generated so if we link on an attribute and the segment is empty we need to know something went wrong.
Yep, could move the second if inside the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?
You can't do this with html or css, but you can do it very easily with jQuery, like this:

```
   $('.navigation a').on("click", function(){
      //This gets the href and splits it on "#". Grabs the value after "#"
      //Make sure to only have 1 # in a link
      var idToFind = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];

      //Check if a div with this ID exists
      if($('#'+idToFind).length > 0){
       //it has been found, you could turn the scrolling to the section into a neat animation here, if you want
      }
      else{
        //It has not found it. Alert.
        alert('"' + idToFind + '" section not found');
      }

  });
```

**edit**
Here's a vanilla js solution:

html:

```
<a href="#foo" onClick="checkSection(this.href)"> bring me to the foo section </a>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkSection(section){
 var idToFind = $(this).getAttribute("href").split("#")[1];
 //Get the element
 var element = document.getElementById(idToFind);

 //check if element exists
 if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
 {
   // exists.
 }
 else{
  //doesn't exist
  alert(idToFind + "doesn't exist");
 } 

}
```

Comment: Won't work. The section is on a different page. `onclick` handler won't do it, the check has to be on the other page.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, that part was not clear to me at all. In this case you could just switch the variable I made from the `a` to the url hashtag, and remove the `a onClick= `. Instead, on the `body` add `onLoad="function();". However, I now see that someone else has answered in this manner, so I guess that person has answered your question for you now. **Edit:** oh, that was you haha.

Comment: I'm not OP. OP answered his own question.